# Are 40-bit integers represented exactly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, v8

I'm using a server-side calculation which needs to generate (with `*` and `+` operations) and compare 40-bit integers. I'm aware that at that point the V8 engine stores the numbers as `Double` rather than `int`. Can I rely on these numbers to be generated and compared correctly?

My intuition says yes - doubles shouldn't have trouble with that - but I'm not sure how to check or where to find information on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes.

A JavaScript [`Number`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19), which is a 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point value, can store integers from -2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>53</sup> without loss of precision, since doubles can store up to 53 bits of mantissa (52 explictly).

**References**:

- [ECMA-262: 4.3.19 Number value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19)
- [Double-precision floating point numbers (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision)

Comment: *Between 252=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 253=9,007,199,254,740,992 the representable numbers are exactly the integers* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision